# Circuit interpretation with a short circuit

Tags: thevenin

[image]

In the following circuit, which has a short circuit between terminals a and b, I do not understand why the resistors are not all in series. For them to be in series the same current must flow through them and since no current flows between terminals a and b Kirchoff's current law implies that the current flowing through all three resistors is equal and is represented by i. Could someone explain why despite having the same current the three resistors are not in series?

Comment: "no current flows through the short circuit" ... citation needed.

Comment: ALL the current flows through a short circuit.

Comment: I meant that no current flows between a and b

Comment: Are you saying that no current flows between A and B because it looks like an open circuit? If so, then it’s not an open circuit. What makes you believe there is no current?

Comment: I think so because there is no path for electrons to flow since air is an insulator

Comment: "which has a **short** circuit between A and B".  In a schematic diagram, when you see a line terminated by a dot (or a circle, or arrow, etc.) with a label (like 'a' or 'b'), then it means **"this is a spot where something will be plugged in later"**.  If the *text* then says there's a short circuit there, then *you* need to imagine (or draw) a short circuit there.  If the text says there's a resistor there, you need to put a resistor there.  If the text says there's a bunny rabbit there, you need to put a bunny rabbit there.  Etc.